# What is the meaning of "Prefix Command" in the keybinding lists on Emacs?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

When I ask Emacs to see a list of key bindings (using C-h b), many key combinations shows "Prefix Command" on its description (like C-h 4 in text-mode or C-c C-v ESC in org-mode). I guess that these combinations could be just the first part of a longer keybinding, but I can't find them anywhere else in the list. What does "Prefix Command" actually mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess that these combinations could be just the first part of a
>   longer keybinding

You are right

```
 but I can't find them anywhere else in the list.
```

I do get them in the list. However one way of getting the keybindings starting with a prefix is to press `Prefix Command`<kbd>C-h</kbd>. For example to get keybindings starting with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>, press <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd>